# how to unit test watch expression in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to unit testing and couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere online, so I thought the community might be able to help. So I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('app')
     .directive('cartSum', function () {
        return {
            template: '<span class="total-amount">{{ sum }}</span>',
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'cartItems'     : '=attrCartItems'
            },
            link: function postLink(scope) {

                scope.sum = 0;

                scope.$watch('cartItems',function(newVal){

                    if (newVal !== undefined) {

                        scope.sum = 0;

                        angular.forEach(newVal, function(item) {

                        scope.sum = (Number(scope.sum) + Number(item.priceUnformatted)).toFixed(2);

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

what I want to test basically is that on $watch the sum is updated but don't know how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The watchers are triggered on the next digest, it has to be something like

```
parentScope = $rootScope.$new();
parentScope.cartItems = [...];

var directive = $compile('<cart-sum attr-cart-items="cartItems">')(parentScope);
parentScope.$digest();
var directiveScope = directive.isolateScope();

expect(directiveScope.sum).toBe(...);
```

Instead of testing watcher, the whole directive and its bindings are involved. This is a problem if the directive is large enough.

The good thing about tests is that they indicate potential design flaws. This one shows why `link` is better place for DOM manipulation, while `controller` is suited to act as viewmodel and handle scope.

It won't happen when controller and watchers can be tested separately:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.cartItems = [...];
$controller('CartSumController', { $scope: scope });
scope.$digest();

expect(scope.sum).toBe(...);
```

Even with controller which was defined within directive, the spec stays straightforward, the only change will be

```
$controller(cartSumDirective[0].controller, { $scope: scope });
```

Comment: I didn't write the code but I thought there was some problem in the logic that makes it more clear thank you!